# React-Table get row where button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, row, react-table

I'm working on a litte React project with React-Table. I have one column with the Header Optionen, where I have a button in every cell.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
render() {
    const columns = [{  
      Header: 'Baumart',  
      accessor: 'baumart'  
     },{  
     Header: 'Größe',  
     accessor: 'größe'  
     },{  
     Header: 'Anzahl',  
     accessor: 'anzahl'  
     },{  
     Header: 'Preis pro Baum',  
     accessor: 'preis'  
     },{  
     Header: 'Optionen',  
     accessor: 'platzhalter',
     Cell: ({ cell }) => (
      <button id="test" onClick={this.deleteRow(this)}>
       Löschen 
      </button>
    )
     }] 
    return (
      <>

        <div className='background'>
        <div id="snowflakes">
        <ParticleBackground/>
        </div>
          <div className='side-grid'>
            <div className='header'>
              <h2>
                <span className='header-l'>
                  Weihnachtsbaumverkauf<br/>
                  Warenkorb
                </span>
                <span className='header-r'><Link to="/shop" className='warenkorb'><img alt='homeicon' src={homeicon} width='32px' height='32px'></img></Link></span>
              </h2>
            </div>
            
            <div className='content'>
            <div>  
              <ReactTable  
                data={this.state.tabledata}  
                columns={columns}   
                showPaginationBottom={false}
              />  
     </div>   
            </div>
            <footer className='footer'><p className='footertext'>Impressum &bull; Datenschutzerklärung<br />Copyright &copy; 2021 - 2022</p></footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>

    );
  }
}
```

These buttons have the job to delete a row with the help of an axios request.

```html
deleteRow(data) {
    return function () {
      api.post('/delete', {
        baumart: data.state.tabledata[0].baumart,
        größe: data.state.tabledata[0].größe
      })
   }
}
```

It works kinda fine, but onClick={this.deleteRow(this)} only gives me the full table as a param and when I click any of my buttons the first row in my table gets removed.

So I had to find a solution...

data.state.tabledata[0].baumart always gives me the baumart of the first row and
data.state.tabledata[1].baumart always gives me the baumart of the second row

Instead of 0 or 1,2,3,4,5...n I need a const or state of the current row where one of my buttons got pressed.

I would be very grateful for every help.

PS: I'm really sorry for my english, still trying to improve it.

Comment: You probably can find a better package for tables in React, but for this case that `Cell` function takes some cell info as an argument, perhaps you can extract the row info from there.

Comment: @tromgy could you show me how? I am fairly new to react and it would be a great help.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give a more definitive answer. Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

`Cell` provides arguments like `value` and `row`, which you can use in order to identify which row's cell was clicked. Following snippet can help you -

```
 Cell: (props) => (
         <button id="test" onClick={alert(JSON.stringify(props))}>
            Löschen 
         </button>
      )
```